# VS2012 Compiler Crash with Variadic Templates

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11, variadic-templates

I am trying to use variadic templates for the first time (using VS2012 + Nov. CTP) and came across an issue where the compiler crashes. Here is a minimal example:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(int someVar) { }
    Foo(int someVar, float someOtherVar) { }
};

template<typename ... FooArguments>
Foo* createFoo(FooArguments ... fooArguments)
{
    return new Foo(1337, fooArguments ...);
}

int main()
{
    delete createFoo(1338.0f); // Works

    delete createFoo(); // Crashes compiler: error MSB6006: "CL.exe" exited with code -2147483645.
}
```

What I am trying to do is have different `Foo` classes which all have the same base class and an identical first argument of the constructor (here `int someVar`). Additionally, they might have constructor overloads which add other arguments (here `float someOtherVar`). They should all be constructible with `createFoo` passing either no or any number of arguments.

I also tried different apporaches like making overloads of `createFoo` that take no arguments, but this obviously results in an ambiguous call.

Why is the compiler crashing? What would be a correct way to do it?

Comment: CTP is a form of Alpha release. While variadic template support was added; it has a huge array of bug reports. Even correct code cannot be guaranteed to work w/ this release.

Comment: So you are saying the code itself is fine and should compile/work on other C++11-compatible compilers?

Comment: Yes, it works fine in VS 12.0 for instance; CTP was basically a huge alpha release.